# reference project issue when convert VS2008 to VS2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I have a shared project (C#) used by several other projects. 
In VS2008, everything compiles fine. Now I convert all to VS2010, then two referencing projects complain that the shared dll not found

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    xmlns:sharedC="clr-namespace:Shared.Converter;assembly=Shared" 
    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <sharedC:BooleanToHiddenVisibility x:Key="boolToVis"/>
```

...

VS2010 compiler complaint about sharedC: BooleanToHiddenVisibilty not found 
the error msg is:
The tag 'BooleanToHiddenVisibility' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:Shared.Convert; assembly=Shared'. Line 14 position 14

I compiled shared.dll first and compilation is successful. 
I removed shared project from reference and add it back. Still the same error 
I checked the path of referenced shared.dll, it is correct

Not sure what I missed.

Comment: Found it. After conversion, project used to target .NET framework 3.5, after conversion, it is changed to target .NET framework 3.5 client profile.  I changed it to .NET 35 and then it compiled successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. After conversion, project used to target .NET framework 3.5, after conversion, it is changed to target .NET framework 3.5 client profile. I change it back to .NET 3.5 framework and it compiles successfully